# Asking a question if I know the answer

Tags: discussion

Should I ask a question if I know the answer, but hope it makes a good discussion?

Comment: Just remember that the goal is not to *discuss a topic* but rather to *answer a question*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable, from the [faq](https://photo.stackexchange.com/faq) "it's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you're on  Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question. "

It can also be a great way of picking up tips from people who give more complete answers

Comment: Indeed! But please give others a shot at answering it, before you do it yourself. You never know, you might learn something new!

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, if it is a neglected area that needs to be illuminated.
**No**, if it seems you are showing off your knowledge are are in search of reputation points.
**But**, wait for others to reply first before providing your own answer.